# Store a list of objects from a stream in hive local db

Tags: flutter, firebase, hive

I have this stream from firebase and i wanna store this product list in hive

```
 static Stream<List<Products>> productStream(){
    return Collections.products.snapshots().map(_productFromSnapshot);
  }
```

Is there a better approach as this example?

```
  Stream getProductStream = DbLogin.productStream();
    getProductStream.listen((doc) {
      List<Product> allProducts = [];
      allProduct.addAll(doc);
      Hive.box(HiveBoxes.allProductBox).addAll(allProduct);
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to approach this, and the best approach may depend on your specific use case.

One approach would be to use the Hive.box method to create a local database, and then use the addAll method to add the data from your stream to the database.

Another approach would be to use the Hive.put method to store the data from your stream in a local file, and then use the get method to retrieve the data from the file.

Finally, you could also use the Hive.sync method to synchronize the data from your stream with a remote database.

Here is an example of how you could use the Hive.box method to create a local database and store the data from your stream:

```
Stream getProductStream = DbLogin.productStream();
    getProductStream.listen((doc) {
      List<Product> allProducts = [];
      allProduct.addAll(doc);
      Hive.box(HiveBoxes.allProductBox).addAll(allProduct);
     });
```